# Using back button for VideoView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I have 6 (List)Fragments in my Activity. If you tap on a element the VideoView will be started. After a video is started and I'm pressing the back button the application finishes the Activity completely instead of going back to the Activity which is holding the Fragments.

In my Activity I'm using the ViewPager and setting the adapter.

I know that the onBackPressed method of my Activity is called when I'm pressing the back button during the video. But how do I handle it when the VideoView is started that it returns back to Activity?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of FragmentTransactions in order to properly allow a backPress to get back to your activity.

If you want an easy but "bad" solution, you could use a variable to know that user is looking a video, and override "onBackPressed" like that :

```
private VideoView isPlaying;
```

where you define your click listeners, register the VideoView playing :

```
isPlaying=video_playing;
```

Then override your OnbackPressed :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isPlaying!=null) {
        isPlaying.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Or anything that make it disappear
        isPlaying=null;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();//If not, let's let the user quit the app correctly
    }
}
```

It is a bad way to deal even if simple because if you have to use your fragment elsewhere, you'll have to handle onBackPressed() exactly the same way somewhere else, and in case of bugs, you'll have to correct it everywhere. Copy/past is a bad pratice when programming.
However, when the project has to progress, that may be a temporary way to make it work, but be aware that if you develop it a lot, you may regret it.